# AXIOS installation issue

Tags: react-native, axios

I am starting with a tutorial to learn react native. I am trying to install **axios** using **npm** but when i do i get the following message. (I am midway through and everything has been going fine until now)

Thanks for your help.

```
npm WARN @babel/plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator@7.0.0-beta.46 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.46 but none was installed.
npm WARN @babel/register@7.0.0-beta.46 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.46 but none was installed.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.2.1 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN react-native-maps@0.21.0 requires a peer of react-native@^0.51 || ^0.52 || ^0.53 || ^0.54 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like it has anything to do with `axios`, what command did you use to install `axios`?

Comment: npm install axios

Comment: Have you tried `npm install --save axios`?

Comment: No - on the website it just said type install...  I can give it a try later - have you done it like that before?

Comment: Yes, that’s actually all I’ve been doing when installing a new module. I followed some tutorials on Idemy, that’s what they’ve been doing as well

Comment: Ok - great. Thanks for the tips. Sounds like we are on a similar journey. Have you made the Pokemon app?